# Getting a bluetooth camera to work in Processing

Tags: image-processing, bluetooth, camera, processing

I'd like to capture video from my Ecamm BT-1 in a Processing sketch.

I've gone through the BT-1 and [hypermedia](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/javadoc/hypermedia/video/package-summary.html) documentation, and think I have concluded that I need to play with Bluetooth in Processing. But, as I have very little experience with Bluetooth I was wondering **if it is at all likely that I'll be able to capture video from a Bluetooth camera?**

..if so, where should I start with learning Bluetooth in Processing?